# how to remove single quotes from a string using truncate in bash

Tags: bash, truncate

In my shell script, condition for a show command is like this:

```
if (arr["bid_present"] == "'true'")
```

In this, I want to remove the single quotes from the boolean data and as the output of the show command should be without single quotes.

Can anyone please help on how to remove these single quotes using tr -d, from the output of the above bash script.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With `awk` you can try like: `awk '{gsub(/\047/,"")} 1' Input_file` to remove all occurrences of `'` from your file.

Comment: Is this a line `if (arr["bid_present"] == "'true'")` present in a file? OR in a script where you have this line you want to remove `'` before true value? Sorry its bit confusing after I re-read the question. Kindly confirm once.

Comment: this if condition is present in a script and i want to remove the single quotes(around true value) from the output of this script via pipe.

Comment: Try like: `awk '{gsub(/\047true\047/,"true")} 1' Input_file` once where keep your script name in place of Input_file name and let me know how it goes.

Comment: i used it before my script but still no output is coming